# Angularjs fails to dynamic change image src

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hello i'm building an application where i want to dynamically change the source of an image in order to force reload it . The problem is that in order of this i only get a broken image on the browser. Instead , if a run the function manually by a button it runs perfect .

HTML document

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app='cameraApp'>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Node JS Camera</title>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <!-- Optional theme -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src='https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.4/angular-sanitize.min.js'></script>
        <script src="cameraApp.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="jumbotron">
                <h1>Welcome to NodeJS Camera v1</h1>
            </div>
            <div ng-controller="HomeController">
                <div class="cameraControl col-md-5">
                    <p>Here is the camera control</p>
                    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="getSnapshot()">Snapshot</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="intervalFunction()">Start Feed</button>    
                </div>
                <div class="lifeFeed col-md-7">
                    <p>Here is the live feed</p>
                    <p><button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="readSnapshot()">Snapshot Read</button></p>
                    <img width='600' height='600' ng-src="{{snapshot}}" alt="SnapShot taken">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

cameraApp.js

```
var cameraApp = angular.module('cameraApp',[]);

cameraApp.controller('HomeController', function($scope,$http,$timeout) {
    function updateImage() {
        var img = 'snapshots/camera.jpg'+  '?decache=' + Math.random();
        console.log('Snapshot Loaded');
        $scope.snapshot = img;  
    };

    $scope.readSnapshot = updateImage;

    $scope.getSnapshot = function() {
        $http.get('/api/getSnapshot')
        .then(function(response) {
            // this callback will be called asynchronously
            // when the response is available
            console.log('Snapshot captured');
            $scope.readSnapshot();
        }, function(response) {
            console.log('Error in capturing...');
        }); 
    }

    $scope.intervalFunction = function() {
        $timeout(function() {
            $scope.getSnapshot();
            $scope.intervalFunction();
        }, 2000);
    };

    // Kick off the interval
    $scope.intervalFunction();
});
```

Comment: What are you getting in console?

Answer (score 1):

There are two solutions I've used for this in the past.

1) Use an ng-if/ng-show on your img tag. This will prevent the broken image from displaying.

```
<img ng-if='snapshot'>
```

2) Set a default image that will load and then be replaced once the other images load.

```
$scope.snapshot = 'snapshots/default.png';
```

Comment: If the function updateImage() is triggered by the button the image load ok , but if it is triggered by $scope.getSnapshot then i get the broken image

Comment: Right below your image tag put {{snapshot}} to see if snapshot is being populated.

Comment: It's being populated just fine , i've managed to get it working by putting the updateImage in a delay shorter than the intervalFunction , but now i get a blinking image as i try to simulate live feed . Is it better to use html canvas?

Comment: Yeah I was going to point out that your other problem is this code is asynchronous. You really need to wait until the image has loaded to call interval again. Like <img onload=getSnapshot> type of deal.